# Tabular table with only two columns

Tags: tabularx

I have a table that includes only 2 columns. I want the column width to be equal the text width (because I believe it looks better?). However, they look a little off so far. Is there a better way to get a simple, nicely looking 2-column table in Latex?

Below are 3 versions of my table:

```
\documentclass[DIV12, a4paper, 12pt, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc]{book}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Search terms and FEARS indices}
  \label{tab1:fears}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
\toprule
  \textbf{Micro FEARS} & \textbf{Macro FEARS} \\
\hline
Job search & National debt  \\
Job openings & The depression  \\
New job & Great depression  \\
Job opportunities & The great depression  \\
Job application & Inflation  \\
Job bank & Inflation rate  \\
Unemployment benefits & Cost of living  \\
Unemployment rate & Recession \\
Unemployment office &   \\
Unemployment insurance & \\
Debt collection & \\
Bankruptcy & \\
Bankruptcy court & \\
Chapter 7 & \\
Filing bankruptcy & \\
Chapter 13 & \\
Credit debt & \\
Debt consolidation & \\
Credit card debt & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Google search terms separated by microeconomic FEARS and macroeconomic FEARS. In total, we have 27 search terms, 19 for microeconomic FEARS and 8 for macroeconomic FEARS.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Search terms and FEARS indices}
  \label{tab1:fears}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}
\toprule
  \textbf{Micro FEARS} & \textbf{Macro FEARS} \\
\hline
Job search & National debt  \\
Job openings & The depression  \\
New job & Great depression  \\
Job opportunities & The great depression  \\
Job application & Inflation  \\
Job bank & Inflation rate  \\
Unemployment benefits & Cost of living  \\
Unemployment rate & Recession \\
Unemployment office &   \\
Unemployment insurance & \\
Debt collection & \\
Bankruptcy & \\
Bankruptcy court & \\
Chapter 7 & \\
Filing bankruptcy & \\
Chapter 13 & \\
Credit debt & \\
Debt consolidation & \\
Credit card debt & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Google search terms separated by microeconomic FEARS and macroeconomic FEARS. In total, we have 27 search terms, 19 for microeconomic FEARS and 8 for macroeconomic FEARS.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Search terms and FEARS indices}
  \label{tab1:fears}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc}
 \toprule
Micro FEARS & Macro FEARS  \\
\midrule
Job search & National debt  \\
Job openings & The depression  \\
New job & Great depression  \\
Job opportunities & The great depression  \\
Job application & Inflation  \\
Job bank & Inflation rate  \\
Unemployment benefits & Cost of living  \\
Unemployment rate & Recession \\
Unemployment office &   \\
Unemployment insurance & \\
Debt collection & \\
Bankruptcy & \\
Bankruptcy court & \\
Chapter 7 & \\
Filing bankruptcy & \\
Chapter 13 & \\
Credit debt & \\
Debt consolidation & \\
Credit card debt & \\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Google search terms separated by microeconomic FEARS and macroeconomic FEARS. In total, we have 27 search terms, 19 for microeconomic FEARS and 8 for macroeconomic FEARS.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have covered all the options in your code for creating tables-- what is the desired output --can u give a hand drawn sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this looks good

[image: des]

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \abovetopsep=1ex % skip before toprule
    \centering
    \caption{Search terms and FEARS indices}
    \label{tab1:fears}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}{%
            @{}>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X
            >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X@{}
            }
            \toprule
            \textbf{Micro FEARS}   & \textbf{Macro FEARS} \\
            \midrule % use \midrule instead of \hline
            Job search             & National debt        \\
            Job openings           & The depression       \\
            New job                & Great depression     \\
            Job opportunities      & The great depression \\
            Job application        & Inflation            \\
            Job bank               & Inflation rate       \\
            Unemployment benefits  & Cost of living       \\
            Unemployment rate      & Recession            \\
            Unemployment office    &                      \\
            Unemployment insurance &                      \\
            Debt collection        &                      \\
            Bankruptcy             &                      \\
            Bankruptcy court       &                      \\
            Chapter 7              &                      \\
            Filing bankruptcy      &                      \\
            Chapter 13             &                      \\
            Credit debt            &                      \\
            Debt consolidation     &                      \\
            Credit card debt       &                      \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \footnotesize
            \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Google search terms separated by microeconomic FEARS and macroeconomic FEARS. In total, we have 27 search terms, 19 for microeconomic FEARS and 8 for macroeconomic FEARS.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Why not 2 regular l type columns?

Comment: @leandriis I took the easiest approach based on the OP's code. Nothing is wrong in handling such a layout. Furthermore, he can tweak the columns and overall table widths to his own taste.

Comment: Thanks! Looks great.

Comment: @MANGo92 In my edit, I used `\midrule` instead of `\hline` so that you can have a proper spacing above and below the rule.

Comment: Thank you, \midrule looks better.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the column width to be equal the text width  (because I believe it looks better?)

Not at all. There are not benefits of make the table wider that it could be, but the opposite. In this case, there are nothing better than `\begin{tabular}{ll}` but if you insist, this could be my approach:

1. Use `tabulary` instead of `tabularx` to set the second column widths proportionally to the contents.
2. Increase `\tabcolsep` as far as possible without produce any line break,  to center a bit the text of these columns.

The result, could be some like this:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx,tabulary}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\tabcolsep3.5em
\belowcaptionskip1ex
\caption{Search terms and FEARS indices}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LL}
\toprule
  \textbf{Micro FEARS} & \textbf{Macro FEARS} \\
\midrule
Job search & National debt  \\
Job openings & The depression  \\
New job & Great depression  \\
Job opportunities & The great depression  \\
Job application & Inflation  \\
Job bank & Inflation rate  \\
Unemployment benefits & Cost of living  \\
... & ... \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```